# JVM Can't Find My Class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

My directory structure looks like this.

**PackagesUnit3/com/myname/start/PackagesTest.java**
(this class contains my main and the import statement "import com.systems.mui.*;)

**PackagesUnit3/com/systems/mui/Test.java**
(this class contains the package statement "package com.systems.mui;")

With PackageUnit3 as my base directory I can compile both classes successfully with the statement

```
"javac com/myname/start/PackagesTest.java"
```

However I cannot run the code with the command

```
"java com.myname.start.PackagesTest"

Error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/myname/start/PackagesTest (wrong name: PackagesTest)"
```

The complier successfully generated `.class` files for each of the java classes and placed them in the same location as the source files.

According to Horstmann, *"Core Java" 9th ed. p. 186,* my "java" command syntax ought to work.

I should not have to specify the current directory (".")because I am not using the classpath (-cp) option.

One note: I used the **"SUBST R: "** command to establish the PackagesUnit3 directory as the base directory. My actual command line looks like **R:>**

Any suggestions??

Comment: +1 because your question title made me laugh. :)

Comment: `java com.myname.start.Packages.test` -- is that a typo? Because your class name is `PackagesTest`.

Comment: I suggest you fix your command line. If your PackagesTest class has the main() method, your command line should be java com.myname.start.PackagesTest.

Comment: @Teifi: The title is funny, but useless, and fails to heed the first law of programming ("It's always your fault.").

Comment: T. J. - it follows Murphy's law - "if anything can go wrong it will" and yes it was a typo in entering the posted message Tom

Comment: FWIW, I vote to keep the title.

Comment: Zealous stack-overflow moderators clearly have no sense of humour

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given the exception, it looks like you're missing a `package` statement:

```
package com.myname.start;
```

Your package declaration should match your directory structure, and then the class will be generated with the correct fully-qualified name of `com.myname.start.PackageTest`.

Either compile in an IDE which will sort things out for you, or compile from the root of your package structure with an optional `-d` argument to specify the root output directory, e.g.

```
$ javac -d bin com/myname/start/*.java
$ java -cp bin com.myname.start.PackageTest
```

Comment: I always work from an IDE, so I'm not an expert, but won't CLASSPATH have to be set somehow?

Comment: @EdwardFalk: Nope - you can always use `-cp` or `--classpath`, but the default is to use the current directory anyway.

Comment: Jon - you are absolutely correct - I did not put the package statement you indicated in the PackagesTest source file. It now runs without the runtime error. T.J. admonition was right on.

Comment: Thanks everyone for taking the time to comment!  Garrett

Answer (score 0):

I've checked on this, recreated the scenario and you're right... Assuming all classes are public, with correct package declarations, and compiling from the root directory, class `Test` will compile succesfully since it doesn't references any other classes (or classes from different packages). No `-cp` option is required

While compiling class `PackagesTest`, it fails to find class `Test`. But by adding `-cp .` , it compiles succesfully.

Once both files are compiled, trying to run `PackagesTest`' main, will also fail to find class `Test`. But by adding `-cp ,` it runs smoothly.

By using the option `-verbose` you can see where is  javac (and java) command looking for classes, as it displays the default classpath, which doesn't contains "." (the local directory)